# where is port 8080 defined in spring cloud app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have been doing a line by line study of the code in [this spring cloud app on github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2) after downloading and installing it on my devbox.  When you type `http://localhost:8080` in your web browser, the content from the `ui` app loads, and is able to interact with the content from the `authserver` and `resource` apps.

`Port 9999` is defined for the `authserver` app, both in the `ui` app's `zuul route` definitions, and also in the `authserver` app's `application.properties`.

Similarly, `port 9000` is defined for the `resource` app, both in the `ui` app's route definitions, and also in the `resource` app's `application.properties`.

But I cannot find any reference to `port 8080`, even after reviewing every line of code in the three apps and also doing a `Ctrl-H` to do full text search of the entire eclipse workspace for the word `8080`.

**So how does the `ui` app know to serve its client content on `port 8080`?**

Comment: It's default unless you change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI module has the following Spring Boot dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That dependency has its own dependencies as seen here:

[Spring Boot Starter Web POM.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-web/pom.xml)

This includes the Spring Boot's Tomcat Starter:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Which brings in the actual Tomcat embedded jars

[Spring Boot Starter Tomcat POM.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/pom.xml)

Because the UI application is a Spring Boot app (eg it uses the Spring Boot Parent POM and has annotated its main class with @SpringBootApplication) it will autoconfigure many things for us based on the Classpath.

Notice the @ConditionalOnClass annotation in this class:

[EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java)

That eventually leads to this class:

[TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java)

Which triggers the startup of the embedded Tomcat server.

The Default Port 8080 setting is actually coming from the embedded Tomcat dependency as seen here:

[org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.java#L152)

```
protected int port = 8080;
```

Comment: Way to go with the references.  Thank you and +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a .properties or .yml file to store all the configuration of your application. There you can define the server port property to listen in whatever port you want.

If you use a .properties file it would be something like this :

```
server.port=8082
```

Or in a .yml file it would be something like this:

```
server:
  port: 8082
```

For more about properties and configuratio in spring, check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html)

Comment: This does not address the OP.  As mentioned in the OP, none of what this respondent mentions seems to be done in the sample app.  The OP asks how the sample app does it.  The direct link to `application.yml` in the sample `ui` app is:  https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: By default, Spring will start your application in port 8080. If you override this in a properties file, it will be started in your port. There is no reference of 8080 in your code because its the default setting of Spring.

Comment: @NickTsitlakidis The default port 8080 is not actually a Spring setting.  It is coming from the embedded Apache Tomcat dependency.  See this answer for more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36586730/1078565

Comment: @punkrocker27ka It's not specific for Tomcat. Using other embedded servers (Undertow or Jetty for example) also sets a default setting of 8080. So I guess Spring sets this up.

Comment: No, it's just a coincidence, that these servlet containers use 8080 as default. Spring doesn't set a default value for the server.port property, it just uses it if it has a custom value set.

Answer (score 1):

there is a reference of all spring boot default properties which should be checked as soon as you hit some unknown defaults :)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html